# Select only those users who have the most visits to provided district

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that selects users with the districts which they visited and visits count.

```
select users.id, places.district, count(users.id) as counts from users
  left join visits on users.id = visits.user_id
  inner join places on visits.place_id = places.id
group by users.id, places.district
```

I need to select only those users who have visited provided district the most. For example, I have a user with id 1 who visited district A one time and district B three times. If I provide district B as parameter, user 1 will be in select. If I want to select users from district A, user 1 will not be in select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's ranking, then filtering:

```
select *
from (
    select u.id, p.district, count(*) as cnt_visits,
        rank() over(partition by u.id order by count(*) desc)
    from users u
    inner join visits v on u.id = v.user_id
    inner join places p on p.id = v.place_id
    group by u.id, p.district
) t
where rn = 1 and district = ?
```

Note that you don't actually need table `users` to get this result. We could simplify the query as:

```
select *
from (
    select v.user_id, p.district, count(*) as cnt_visits,
        rank() over(partition by u.id order by count(*) desc)
    from visits v
    inner join places p on p.id = v.place_id
    group by v.user_id, p.district
) t
where rn = 1 and district = ?
```

This query handles top ties: if a user had the same, maximum number of visits in two different districts, both are taken into account. If you don't need that feature, then we can simplify the subquery with `distinct on`:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (v.user_id) v.user_id, p.district, count(*) as cnt_visits
    from visits v
    inner join places p on p.id = v.place_id
    group by v.user_id, p.district
    order by v.user_id, cnt_visits desc
) t
where district = ?
```

Comment: Thank you for response. The last query solved my problem.